# is_uploaded_file array given error

Tags: file-upload, php

i have this error in my upload file. The syntax is correct, where is the problem?

The error:

> is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\bena_website\admin\variables\upload_img.php on line 34

```
<h3>Please Choose a File and click Submit</h3>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
            <input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

<?php
        // check if a file was submitted
        if(!isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
            echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
        }
        else
            {
            print_r( $_FILES );
            try {
                upload();
                // give praise and thanks to the php gods
                echo '<p>Thank you for submitting</p>';
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
            }
        }
// the upload function
function upload(){

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

    // check the file is less than the maximum file size
    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize)
        {
    // prepare the image for insertion
    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
    // $imgData = addslashes($_FILES['userfile']);

    // get the image info..
      $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

    // put the image in the db...
      // database connection
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR DIE (mysql_error());

      // select the db
      mysql_select_db ("bena") OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

    // our sql query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testblob
            ( image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name)
            VALUES
            ('', '{$size['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '{$size[3]}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}')";

    // insert the image
    if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo 'Unable to upload file';
        }
    }
}
else {
     // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
     echo
      '<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
      <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.'</div>
      <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].' bytes</div>
      <hr />';
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess you have multiple file-inputs there or 1 with the name userfile**[]**

Comment: I have a feeling Pekka is thinking the same, but I reckon you are posting multiple files in your form? In this case, `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` will hold an array of paths. On second thoughts, your variable names (`userfile`) looks like you're only uploading one file. In this case, please `print_r()` the `$_FILES` array and add it to your question :-)

Comment: please delete your comment and post the complete code by editing your question

Comment: Since the problem is in fact located here, please check my answer as OK.

Answer (score 7):

Emit at the start of the upload() function the structure of the $_FILES array to learn, what's inside the structure:

```
print_r( $_FILES );
```

As written in one of the comments, if you have a form like

```
<form ... method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="userfile[0]" />
   <input type="file" name="userfile[1]" />
   ...
</form>
```

or

```
<form ... method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">>
   <input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
   <input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
   ...
</form>
```

you need the access this

```
$_FILES[ 'userfile' ][ 'tmp_name' ]
```

like an array:

```
$_FILES['userfile'][ 'tmp_name' ][ 0 ]
$_FILES['userfile'][ 'tmp_name' ][ 1 ]
```

Comment: i hope you got the correct point...

Comment: @KoolKabin: Something wrong with my answer?

Comment: no not at all i mean you got the correct point...

Comment: @Stefan Pantke here is the content of $_FILES:Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 2011_Welcome.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\tmp\php2EED.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 23463 ) ) )  it wasn't duplicated, is it?

Comment: @aida: No, but you need to access the name using: $_FILES['userfile'][ 'tmp_name' ][ 0 ]. Have a look just behind 'Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] =>'. [name] points to an array value.

Comment: Please check, if the source of the posting form reads like <input type="file" name="userfile[]" /> in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check to see if `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` is different from zero. 
If it's 2, for instance, then the file size is larger than the size set in HTML.
For more info on error messages check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php